# Typescript type not narrowed in generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-narrowing

Take for example the following types.

```
type ZoneAndTools = {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: object,
}

type ZoneTypes = keyof ZoneAndTools;
```

Applied to this function, I'm looking for to extract the type from a map

```
function transform<T extends ZoneTypes>(
    map: Map<T, ZoneAndTools[T]>,
    key: T
): ZoneAndTools[T] | undefined {
    return map.get(key);
}
```

And here is a use case :

```
const a: Map<ZoneTypes, ZoneAndTools[ZoneTypes]> = new Map();
const b = transform(a, 'a');
// b is string | number | object | undefined instead of number | undefined
```

My question to the experts, why doesn't the transform function in this use case return `number> | undefined` ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=29&pln=17&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAWg9gOwgQQQEwCpzgGwM5QC8UA3gFBSVQCGAXFAgK4C2ARhAE4A0FVr9eYBwCWCAOY8qUAMb04rAFYRpwHgF8yZUJFiIIGcBALEA1hBBwAZrqSpM2fAG5NZS4wQrhiKEOoI8lnAczAA8GFAQAB7AEOgE8EgGkHgAfAAUvJTM1GD0ALI5YVw2KOhYuHgA2hgAuimSVGYg9BhkAJT0CaX2FdU1UAA+UO5oEJaiEGikmVAcEMCMHAhQ2WAAdGLzaU1tzhpk0oiCNPmFXUlGxV125fiV54Z4dUQMEADuUAVgabsHR8BQVgvXz+QLBNLUYoAcmoUN+QA)

Comment: What's with the global `this` in the question?  Seems kind of weird.

Comment: @jcalz my bad, It was from the original code.

Comment: [This example](https://tsplay.dev/NVakGw) demonstrates the problem.  Do you want me to write this up as an answer?  Or should we try to get user3133's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70930804/2887218) to explain that.

Comment: With `T = 'a'` (the key) I would have expected the compiler to infer that `ZoneAndTools[T]` to be `number`. Am I having to high expection toward the compiler ?

Comment: But `T` is not `"a"`. If it *were*, then yes, that would happen.  But it's not, and [cannot be](https://tsplay.dev/WoD5Pw), because you are not passing a valid `Map<"a", ZoneAndTools["a"]>`, as the example shows.  The compiler is behaving correctly here.  (Note that you're asking "why is this happening" and not "how can I properly write the  `transform()` call signature to achieve my desired intent".  For *that* question I'd say [these](https://tsplay.dev/mqEkdm) approaches might suffice, but that's out of scope here.)

Comment: Yep thank you for your patience, I think I got it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is because you give the map type ZoneTypes, which could be any of those.

```
const a: Map<ZoneTypes, ZoneAndTools["a"]> = new Map();
```

You should strictly type it, as you already know the `ZoneAndTools` is type of `a`

```
const a: Map<"a", ZoneAndTools["a"]> = new Map();
```

You could also type this furher and create custom `Map` for `ZoneAndTools`

```
type ZoneAndTools = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: object;
};

type ZoneTypes = keyof ZoneAndTools;

function transform<T extends ZoneTypes>(
  map: Map<T, ZoneAndTools[T]>,
  key: T
): ZoneAndTools[T] | undefined {
  return map.get(key);
}

type ZoneMap<T extends ZoneTypes> = Map<T, ZoneAndTools[T]>

const a: ZoneMap<"a"> = new Map();
const b = transform(a, "a");
```

Comment: This is the right answer but it's not obvious why `Map<K1, V>` should not be assignable to `Map<K2, V>` if `K1 extends K2`.  Looks like it's the `forEach()` method which could do unsafe things with the key.  Do you want to mention this here or should I post a separate answer?

Comment: @jcalz even though `ZoneAndTools` is defined in map creation, T is used for `ZoneTypes` which could be any of those types, and it is used in transform as arbitary T to define the outcome of the function (which would be any of types defined for map)

Comment: My problem is that my `Map` has every value of ZoneTypes as key.

Comment: wow that made no sense, let me be more clear; transform uses T, which could be any of `ZoneTypes` to define the outcome, map is defined with `ZoneTypes` which again would be any of those. transform can not know what type of ZoneTypes the map is, because it is not defined.

Comment: Can you explain why that's an issue?  I can use a value of type `{a: string, b: string}` in a place that expects just `{a: string}`, by structural subtyping.  But a similar assignment with `Map` does not work; `Map<"a" | "b", string>` cannot be assigned to `Map<"a", string>`.  Do you have reasoning for why `Map` specifically behaves this way?  The fact that `"a" | "b"` is wider than `"a"` is not, in and of itself, a reason.